# Pyspark | Transform RDD from key with list of values > values with list of keys

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

In pyspark, how to transform an input RDD where **Every Key has a list of Values** to an output RDD where **Every Value has a list of Keys it belong to**?

**Input**

```
[(1, ['a','b','c','e']), (2, ['b','d']), (3, ['a','d']), (4, ['b','c'])]
```

**Output**

```
[('a', [1, 3]), ('b', [1, 2, 4]), ('c', [1, 4]), ('d', [2,3]), ('e', [1])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten and swap the key value on the rdd first, and then `groupByKey`:

```py
rdd.flatMap(lambda r: [(k, r[0]) for k in r[1]]).groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()
# [('a', [1, 3]), ('e', [1]), ('b', [1, 2, 4]), ('c', [1, 4]), ('d', [2, 3])]
```

Comment: How can I make mapValues(list) work when the input has 1 key but 2 values (Int, String, List)?